# Are all entrywise nonnegative positive semidefinite matrices has a rank-1 decomposition with nonnegative vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, positive-matrices

I know that all positive semidefinite matrices has a rank-1 decomposition. (Equivalently, all quadratic nonnegative polynomial is sum of squares of linear function.)

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^r x_i x_i^T = X X^T$$.

I am wondering if there is an **entrywise nonnegative** X satisfying $A=X X^T$ if $A$ is a **entrywise nonnegative** positive semidefinite matrix. The converse is obviously true..

I think an important tool is that solution set of $A=X X^T$ is closed with the operation $X \rightarrow XP$ where the $P$ is an orthonormal matrix. For example,
$$a^T
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}a$$

can be represented as $(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2 + (a_1 - a_3)^2$, but with multiplying by

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

we get an 'positive representation', $\frac{1}{2}(2a_1+a_2)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(a_2 + 2a_3)^2$.

Comment: J.E. Maxfield, H. Minc, On the equation X'X = A, Proc. EdinburghMath. Soc. 13 (1962) 125–129.

I found this is false. There is an counterexample in this paper with $n = 5$. Entrywise nonnegative positive semidefinite matrix is called doubly nonnegative(DNN) and a matrix that can be represented as $XX^T$ with  nonnegative X is called completely positive matrix(CP).